# Can JMonkey Engine be used without shaders?

Tags: java

I want to know whether JMonkey engine (the new redesign after the new team came on in 2009) can run without shaders.  I need a game engine that will work on older machines which may not support shaders.  I understand that JMonkey engine has a lot of shader features that I obviously won't be able to use if I don't have support for shaders, but is it possible to use the engine (the fixed-function pipeline for graphics and then everything else: scene graph, physics, etc.) without needing to have support for shaders?

If it can run without shaders, how do I get that to happen?  Hello world crashes because I don't have them.  (I will update this post with an actual error message if no one knows what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see JMonkey engine 3 can only be used with shaders. See [JME3 and Shaders](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3aadvanced%3ajme3_shaders). Quote from the linked page:

```
You probably heard that JME3 is “shader oriented”, but what does that mean?
Usually to use shaders you must create what is called a program. This program 
specify the vertex shader and the fragment shader to use.
JME3 encloses this in the material system. Every material in JME3 uses shaders.
```